# How to split value from a string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, xml-parsing, html-parser

My example string is listed here. i want to split every value result in array or hash to process value of each element.

```
<div id="test">
           accno:          123232323 <br>
           id:            5443534534534 <br>
           name:            test_name <br>
           url:                  www.google.com <br>

 </div>
```

How can i fetch each values in a hash or array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regex it's easy:

```
s = '<div id="test">
           accno:          123232323 <br>
           id:            5443534534534 <br>
           name:            test_name <br>
           url:                  www.google.com <br>

 </div>'

 p s.scan(/\s+(.*?)\:\s+(.*?)<br>/).map.with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i[0].to_sym] = i[1].strip }
```

Or you can precise you keys (accno, id, name, url) like `([a-z]+)` if they contains only lower case letters:

```
 p s.scan(/\s+([a-z]+)\:\s+(.*?)<br>/).map.with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i[0].to_sym] = i[1].strip }
```

Result:

```
 {:accno=>"123232323", :id=>"5443534534534", :name=>"test_name", :url=>"www.google.com"}
```

**Update**

in case of:

```
<div id="test"> accno: 123232323 id: 5443534534534 name: test_name url: www.google.com </div>
```

regex will be:

```
 /([a-z]+)\:\s*(.*?)\s+/
```

`([a-z]+)` - this is hash key, and it could contains `-` or `_`, then just add it like: `([a-z]+\-_)`. This scheme presume that after key follows `:` (perhaps with space) and then some text until the space. Or `(\s+|<)` at the end if line ends without space: `url: www.google.com</div>`

Comment: Thanks @zishe. I can able fetch every values in a hash. Suppose if string like this                                                      s = '<div id="test">
           accno:          123232323
           id:            5443534534534
           name:            test_name
           url:                  www.google.com

 </div>' . if string without <br> , then how can i get the same result. If 'accno:          123232323 ' is present somewhere in the string. then how can i get same result.

Comment: You can also firstly extract test block: `block = s.scan(/<div id="test">(.*?)<\/div>/m)[0][0]` (it's also string) and then apply regex to it, to prevent undesirable results. Moreover, i recommend you to do this, because regex depends mostly from `:`, so it can easily match with some other content on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing html, use a html/xml parser like [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to pull out the text content of the required `<div>` tag using a [CSS selector](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/). Then parse the text into fields.

To install nokogiri:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

Then process the page and text:

```
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

# re matches: spaces (word) colon spaces (anything) space
re_fields  = /\s+(?<field>\w+):\s+(?<data>.*?)\s/

# Somewhere to store the results
record = {}

page      = Nokogiri::HTML( open("http://example.com/divtest.html") )

# Select the text from <div id=test> and scan into fields with the regex 
page.css( "div#test" ).text.scan( re_fields ){ |field, data|
    record[ field ] = data
}
p record
```

Results in:

```
{"accno"=>"123232323", "id"=>"5443534534534", "name"=>"test_name", "url"=>"www.google.com"}
```

The `page.css( "blah" )` selector can also be accessed as an array if you are processing multiple elements, which can be looped through with `.each`

```
# Somewhere to store the results
records    = []

# Select the text from <div id=test> and scan into fields with the regex 
page.css( "div#test" ).each{ |div| 
    record = {}
    div.text.scan( re_fields ){ |field, data|
        record[field] = data
    }
    records.push record
}
p records
```

Comment: @karan This would be better if page is big and you should precise block in which contents with your data present. Great solution.

Comment: I just wanted to note the html processing as some people go to great lengths to make that part difficult. The actual field processing is basically the same as your answer.